# How to get field values from a query using NEST with Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm new to elastic search and using (trying to) the NEST Library. I'm writing logs to an index using Serilog Elastic Search Sink. So first consideration is I have no control over the structure that the sink uses, just the structured logging properties that I choose to log.

Anyway, I'm simply trying to run a basic search where I want to return the first X documents from an index. I'm able to get some of the property values back from the query but nothing for any of the fields.

The query is as follows:

```
var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<LogsViewModel>(s => s
       .Index("webapp-razor-*")
       .From(0)
       .Size(5)
       .Query(q => q.MatchAll()));
```

I'm guessing the reason I'm returning null for the fields is because the model class is not structured correctly.

Ruuning the console tool within the elastic search portal for a simply GET Request:

[image]

An example document returned from this query is below:

```
{
        "_index" : "webapp-razor-2021.05",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "34v3t43kBwE34t3vJowGRgl",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2021-05-03T20:19:46.9329848+01:00",
          "level" : "Information",
          "messageTemplate" : "{@LogEventCategory}{@LogEventType}{@LogEventSource}{@LogCountry}{@LogRegion}{@LogCity}{@LogZip}{@LogLatitude}{@LogLongitude}{@LogIsp}{@LogIpAddress}{@LogMobile}{@LogUserId}{@LogUsername}{@LogForename}{@LogSurname}{@LogData}",
          "message" : "\"Open Id Connect\"\"User Sign In\"\"WebApp-RAZOR\"\"United Kingdom\"\"England\"\"MyTown\"\"PX27\"\"54.8951\"\"-9.1585\"\"My ISP\"\"123.345.789.180\"\"False\"\"a8vce3vc-8e61-44fc-b142-93ck396ad91ce\"\"joe@email.net\"\"joe@email.net\"\"Bloggs\"\"User with username [joe@email.net] forename [joe@email.net] surname [Bloggs] from IP Address [123.345.789.180] signed into the application [WebApp_RAZOR] Succesfully\"",
          "fields" : {
            "LogEventCategory" : "Open Id Connect",
            "LogEventType" : "User Sign In",
            "LogEventSource" : "WebApp-RAZOR",
            "LogCountry" : "United Kingdom",
            "LogRegion" : "England",
            "LogCity" : "MyTown",
            "LogZip" : "PX27",
            "LogLatitude" : "54.8951",
            "LogLongitude" : "-9.1585",
            "LogIsp" : "My ISP",
            "LogIpAddress" : "123.345.789.180",
            "LogMobile" : "False",
            "LogUserId" : "a8vce3vc-8e61-44fc-b142-93ck396ad91ce",
            "LogUsername" : "joe@email.net",
            "LogForename" : "joe@email.net",
            "LogSurname" : "Bloggs",
            "LogData" : "User with username [joe@email.net] forename [Joe] surname [Bloggs] from IP Address [123.345.789.180] signed into the application [WebApp_RAZOR] Succesfully",
            "RequestId" : "0HM8ED1IRB7AK:00000001",
            "RequestPath" : "/signin-oidc",
            "ConnectionId" : "0HM8ED1IRB7AK",
            "MachineName" : "DESKTOP-OS52032",
            "MemoryUsage" : 23688592,
            "ProcessId" : 26212,
            "ProcessName" : "WebApp-RAZOR",
            "ThreadId" : 6
          }
```

Sample model class (or part of it)

```
public class LogsViewModel
{
    [JsonProperty("@timestamp")]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("level")]
    public string Level { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public Fields Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    [JsonProperty("LogEventCategory")]
    public string LogEventCategory { get; set; }

    // Not all propeties shown here but would be the same principal...
}
```

Could someone please give me an idea in how to go about this? once I know how to get the values from the fields such as "LogEventCategory" then I should be able to move forward and figure it out. None of the documentation examples for Elastic has worked for me, thanks

Comment: You may be interested in using the ECS formatter for Serilog, which will format log messages with the Elastic Common Schema structure: https://github.com/elastic/ecs-dotnet/tree/master/src/Elastic.CommonSchema.Serilog. It should be possible then to fetch a collection of ECS `Base` types from an index. Using ECS across applications can bring a unified logging structure, making searching, aggregating across logs from disparate sources easier.

Comment: Thanks Russ, I will look into this. The other challenge I find is if returning the logs from a query using <dynamic>, although I can fetch all the relevant fields, some fields are not present in every document returned so if I try and get the values from missing keys, I run into exceptions. I'm trying to figure out a solution using dynamic json parsing where I can set a default value for a property if the key is missing from a particular log event. (note that i'm logging to Elastic from various different apps so not all structures from the Serilog sinks will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of trial and error, I finally derived a solution in being able to pull the fields of choice from the _source object in the elastic document. There may well be a more optimized approach here so welcome any feedback on the topic.

My first step was to view the structure of a sample document from an index that Serilog is writing to, note in my case I'm not necessarily including all structured log event properties in all log events being written to Elastic i.e. on system startup, I simply don't need details of the user/location etc.

Using the DevTools in the Elastic Portal, I performed a simple GET request:

[image]

Great tip from user Russ Cam in the comments above where he advises the advantage in using the NuGet package for [Elastic Common Schema .NET](https://github.com/elastic/ecs-dotnet) which provides some standardization for using Serilog and logging to Elastic from various different apps/sources. Reading the forums it looks to be that Elastic are strongly encouraging us to use a common schema as it will play better when working with charts/metrics/dashboards creation etc.

My WebApp is using .NET Core 5, I've included the code section below used in Program.cs file that shows where I added the reference to the above Elastic Common Schema .NET library. Now because I'm connecting to Elastic Cloud, I have to include the authentication details when building the Elastic client and it took me a few attempts before I figured out how to incorporate this package reference alongside some of the other Elastic Client options:

Program.cs file:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile(path: "appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        // Credentials used for eleastic cloud logging sink.
        var elkUri = configuration.GetSection("ElasticCloud").GetValue<string>("Uri");
        var elkUsername = configuration.GetSection("ElasticCloud").GetValue<string>("Username");
        var elkPassword = configuration.GetSection("ElasticCloud").GetValue<string>("Password");
        var elkApplicationName = configuration.GetSection("ElasticCloud").GetValue<string>("ApplicationName");

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(elkUri))
            {
                ModifyConnectionSettings = x => x.BasicAuthentication(elkUsername, elkPassword),
                IndexFormat = "webapp-razor-{0:yyyy.MM}",
                AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                CustomFormatter = new EcsTextFormatter() // *Elastic Common Schema .NET package ref HERE*
            })
            .CreateLogger();

        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

        string logEventCategory = "WebApp-RAZOR";
        string logEventType = "Application Startup";
        string logEventSource = "System";
        string logData = "";

        try
        {
            // Tested OK 1.5.2021
            //throw new Exception(); // Testing only..

            logData = "Application Starting Up";

            Log.Information(
                "{@LogEventCategory}" +
                "{@LogEventType}" +
                "{@LogEventSource}" +
                "{@LogData}",
                logEventCategory,
                logEventType,
                logEventSource,
                logData);

            host.Run(); // Run the WebHostBuilder.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logData = "The Application failed to start correctly.";

            // Tested on 08/07/2020
            Log.Fatal(ex,
                "{@LogEventCategory}" +
                "{@LogEventType}" +
                "{@LogEventSource}" +
                "{@LogData}",
                logEventCategory,
                logEventType,
                logEventSource,
                logData);
        }
        finally // Cleanup code.
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        };
    }
```

My methodology in using a dynamic type reference in the NEST Client method is so I can avoid using a strongly typed model, this made made life much easier when trying to figure out what the structure was of the data returned from the query by pausing the result on debug and having a peek inside the content structure.

```
var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<dynamic>(s => s
      //.AllIndices()
      .Index("webapp-razor-*")
      .Query(q => q
      .MatchAll()
       )
);

// Once the searchResponse data is returned from the query, 
// I then map the results to a View Model 
// (which I use for rendering the list of results to my Razor page)
LogsViewModel = new LogsViewModel
{
     ScannedEventCount = searchResponse.Hits.Count,
     LogEventProperties = new List<LogEventProperties>()
};

foreach (var doc in searchResponse.Documents)
{
    var lep = new LogEventProperties();

    lep.Timestamp = DateTime.Parse(doc["@timestamp"].ToString());
    lep.Level = doc["log.level"];
    // Properties
    if (((IDictionary<string, object>)doc).ContainsKey("_metadata"))
    {
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_event_category", out object value1)) { lep.LogEventCategory = value1.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_event_type", out object value2)) { lep.LogEventType = value2.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_event_source", out object value3)) { lep.LogEventSource = value3.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_device_id", out object value4)) { lep.LogDeviceId = value4.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_country", out object value5)) { lep.LogCountry = value5.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_region", out object value6)) { lep.LogRegion = value6.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_city", out object value7)) { lep.LogCity = value5.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_zip", out object value8)) { lep.LogZip = value5.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_latitude", out object value9)) { lep.LogLatitude = value9.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_longitude", out object value10)) { lep.LogLongitude = value10.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_isp", out object value11)) { lep.LogIsp = value5.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_ip_address", out object value12)) { lep.LogIpAddress = value12.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_mobile", out object value13)) { lep.LogMobile = value13.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_user_id", out object value14)) { lep.LogUserId = value14.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_username", out object value15)) { lep.LogUsername = value15.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_forename", out object value16)) { lep.LogForename = value16.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_surname", out object value17)) { lep.LogSurname = value17.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("log_data", out object value18)) { lep.LogData = value18.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("request_id", out object value19)) { lep.RequestId = value19.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("request_path", out object value20)) { lep.RequestPath = value20.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("connection_id", out object value21)) { lep.ConnectionId = value21.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["_metadata"]).TryGetValue("memory_usage", out object value22)) { lep.MemoryUsage = (Int64)value22; }
    }
    // Exception
    if (((IDictionary<string, object>)doc).ContainsKey("error"))
    {
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["error"]).TryGetValue("message", out object value23)) { lep.ErrorMessage = value23.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["error"]).TryGetValue("type", out object value24)) { lep.ErrorType = value24.ToString(); }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["error"]).TryGetValue("stack_trace", out object value25)) { lep.ErrorStackTrace = value25.ToString(); }
    }
    // Machine Name
    if (((IDictionary<string, object>)doc).ContainsKey("host"))
    {
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["host"]).TryGetValue("name", out object value26)) { lep.MachineName = value26.ToString(); }
    }
    // Process
    if (((IDictionary<string, object>)doc).ContainsKey("process"))
    {
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["process"]["thread"]).TryGetValue("id", out object value27)) { lep.ThreadId = (Int64)value27; }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["process"]).TryGetValue("pid", out object value28)) { lep.ProcessId = (Int64)value28; }
        if (((IDictionary<String, object>)doc["process"]).TryGetValue("name", out object value29)) { lep.ProcessName = value29.ToString(); }
     }
     LogsViewModel.LogEventProperties.Add(lep);
   }
}

return View(LogsViewModel);
```

The fundamental reason I went with the above method is that some of the documents will not contain all of the structured logging event properties. I had to to derive a way in checking for the existence of the dictionary keys before trying to access the values, otherwise I'd get exception errors when the keys are missing. An example of this is the difference observed between a log event that was generated during an exception versus a log information event for when a user logged into the app.

The two documents below show a slightly different JSON structure which emphasises my decision to fetch the results using a dynamic type. In general, for any documents that I create myself into Elastic, I would usually map the items to a proper model given I would always know ow the full structure beforehand.

```
  {
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 70,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "webapp-razor-2021.05",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "_2sOPnkBwE4YgJownxnP",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2021-05-05T20:43:34.6041763+01:00",
          "log.level" : "Information",
          "message" : "\"WebApp-RAZOR\"\"Application Startup\"\"System\"\"Application Starting Up\"",
          "_metadata" : {
            "message_template" : "{@LogEventCategory}{@LogEventType}{@LogEventSource}{@LogData}",
            "log_event_category" : "WebApp-RAZOR",
            "log_event_type" : "Application Startup",
            "log_event_source" : "System",
            "log_data" : "Application Starting Up",
            "memory_usage" : 4680920
          },
          "ecs" : {
            "version" : "1.5.0"
          },
          "event" : {
            "severity" : 2,
            "timezone" : "GMT Standard Time",
            "created" : "2021-05-05T20:43:34.6041763+01:00"
          },
          "host" : {
            "name" : "DESKTOP-OS52032"
          },
          "log" : {
            "logger" : "Elastic.CommonSchema.Serilog",
            "original" : null
          },
          "process" : {
            "thread" : {
              "id" : 9
            },
            "pid" : 3868,
            "name" : "WebApp-RAZOR",
            "executable" : "WebApp-RAZOR"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "webapp-razor-2021.05",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "AGsOPnkBwE4YgJowyBrP",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2021-05-05T20:43:44.3936344+01:00",
          "log.level" : "Information",
          "message" : "\"Open Id Connect\"\"User Sign In\"\"WebApp-RAZOR\"\"United Kingdom\"\"England\"\"MyTown\"\"OX26\"\"51.8951\"\"-1.1585\"\"My ISP\"\"123.456.789.101\"\"False\"\"34vc34-34v34534-44fc-b142-32223ad91ce\"\"joe.bloggs@email.net\"\"joe.bloggs@email.net\"\"Bloggs\"\"User with username [joe.bloggs@email.net] forename [Jose] surname [Bloggs] from IP Address [123.345.789.101] signed into the application [WebApp_RAZOR] Succesfully\"",
          "_metadata" : {
            "message_template" : "{@LogEventCategory}{@LogEventType}{@LogEventSource}{@LogCountry}{@LogRegion}{@LogCity}{@LogZip}{@LogLatitude}{@LogLongitude}{@LogIsp}{@LogIpAddress}{@LogMobile}{@LogUserId}{@LogUsername}{@LogForename}{@LogSurname}{@LogData}",
            "log_event_category" : "Open Id Connect",
            "log_event_type" : "User Sign In",
            "log_event_source" : "WebApp-RAZOR",
            "log_country" : "United Kingdom",
            "log_region" : "England",
            "log_city" : "MyTown",
            "log_zip" : "OX26",
            "log_latitude" : "55.1234",
            "log_longitude" : "-10.1585",
            "log_isp" : "My ISP",
            "log_ip_address" : "123.456.789.101",
            "log_mobile" : "False",
            "log_user_id" : "34vc34-34v3434-44fc-b142-32223ad91ce",
            "log_username" : "joe.bloggs@email.net",
            "log_forename" : "joe.bloggs@email.net",
            "log_surname" : "Bloggs",
            "log_data" : "User with username [joe.bloggs@email.net] forename [Joe] surname [Bloggs] from IP Address [123.456.789.101] signed into the application [WebApp_RAZOR] Succesfully",
            "request_id" : "0HM8FVO9FFHDD:00000001",
            "request_path" : "/signin-oidc",
            "connection_id" : "0HM8FVO9FFHDD",
            "memory_usage" : 23954480
          },
          "ecs" : {
            "version" : "1.5.0"
          },
          "event" : {
            "severity" : 2,
            "timezone" : "GMT Standard Time",
            "created" : "2021-05-05T20:43:44.3936344+01:00"
          },
          "host" : {
            "name" : "DESKTOP-OS52032"
          },
          "log" : {
            "logger" : "Elastic.CommonSchema.Serilog",
            "original" : null
          },
          "process" : {
            "thread" : {
              "id" : 16
            },
            "pid" : 3868,
            "name" : "WebApp-RAZOR",
            "executable" : "WebApp-RAZOR"
          }
        }
      },
```